# Firebase/Ruby: google-protobuf gem not found by aws lamda

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda, rubygems, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use the google-cloud-firestore gem for an AWS Lamda function, but I cannot get it to find the google-protobuf gem.

I have several gems, all of which work fine with the lamda function, but adding the firestore gem yielded errors in the protobuf gem.

I used bundler to install google-cloud-firestore, for some reason I'm only having an issue with this gem.

Here's the error lamda spits out:

```
"errorMessage": "Could not find 'google-protobuf' (~> 3.18) among 455 total gem(s)\nChecked in 'GEM_PATH=/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0:/opt/ruby/gems/3.2.0:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/ruby/3.2.0' at: /var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/specifications/googleapis-common-protos-types-1.10.0.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information",
  "errorType": "Init<Gem::MissingSpecError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1466:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies'"
```

But google-protobuf is in my gem folder, called "google-protobuf-3.25.0-x86_64-linux". Every other gem is in the same folder, but they work just fine.

Comment: Familiar with Google Cloud (Firestore) and protobuf but not with Ruby and AWS (Lambda). I was able to create a basic Ruby Firestore client locally and it worked. Are you able to run your code locally? Multiple protobuf implementations (including Ruby) depend on a shared C implementation that may require compilation on use, could this be an issue w/ AWS Lambda's runtime environment? You confirm that `google-protobuf` is in "my gem folder" is this the local copy or the deployed copy of the gem? Can you demonstrate that `google-protobuf` is deployed correctly to AWS Lambda?

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm able to run my code locally just fine. However, I'm using a M1 Mac, so the protobuf version is based on ARM64 architecture. However in AWS I need to use the x86_64_linux version of protobuf, which is the only difference in my package structure. I'm not sure if it is an issue with Lamda's runtime environment, also the protobuf is indeed in the deployed copy of the gem.

Comment: I'm outta ideas, sorry. Hopefully someone more familiar with Ruby on AWS Lambda can help us out.

Comment: Hey I figured out the issue, I believe it's that AWS employs a arm64-linux architecture, but my MacOS device only installs these gems based on arm64-darwin architecture, I have no idea how to override bundler what files to modify in order to install it as if it was on arm-64-linux architecture, any ideas?